# how do I convert DAQ-derived mxd file format to csv?

Tags: parsing, format, gis

**Background:**

- I was given a pile of yokagawa "mxd" files without documentation or
  description, and told "convert it".
- I have looked for documentation and found none.  The OEM doesn't seem to "do" reproducibility in the sense of a "code book". ([link](http://tmi.yokogawa.com/us/service-support/faqs/where-can-i-find-documentation-describing-the-wdf-file-format/))
- I have looked for online code for converters and found none.
- National Instruments has a connector, but only if I use latest/greatest
  LabVIEW ([link](http://www.ni.com/example/52719/en/)).  I don't have that version.

The only compatible suffix is from ArcGIS, but why would DAQ use a format like that.

**Questions:**

- Is there a straightforward way to convert "mxd" to "csv"?
- How do I find the relationship using the binary data?  Eyeballing HEX seems slow/inefficient.
- Is there any relationship between DAQ mxd and ArcGIS mxd?

Comment: Without any additional information this is impossible to answer/convert. Who gave you the data for what purposes and into what do you need to convert it? What is the origin of the data, measurement device,....?

Comment: It was from a Yokogawa DAQ card, unknown type.  That was referenced in the links.  One of my buddies gave it to me, but he doesn't have any format details either.  It is from an older test system of some sort that he is measuring for a research project.  I don't know that showing hex-code is so helpful as there is a lot of file and not a lot of screen.  I was hoping it was like older PowerPoint, as in zipped and given a new suffix, or SQLite.  It could be ArcGIS in disguise for all I know.  I was hoping for pointers or other direction outside of "tough luck".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yokogawa supplies a progam called MX100 Standard Software: https://y-link.yokogawa.com/YL008/?Download_id=DL00002238&Language_id=EN, this program can read the *.mxd files and also export them to ascii or excel. See the well hidden manual: http://web-material3.yokogawa.com/IMMX180-01E_040.pdf, page 105 has chapter 3.7: converting data formats.