# how do I convert a big stack of DAQ-derived mxd file format to csv?

Tags: parsing, automation, format

**Background**

I asked this question:
[how do I convert DAQ-derived mxd file format to csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44269186/how-do-i-convert-daq-derived-mxd-file-format-to-csv)

The answer was good and relevant then, but now I have upwards near a thousand files to process.  The last thing I can do is manually process them one at a time.  In their compressed form they are a good number of GB.  There seem to be ~100k rows per file.

When I try to load them, it get this:
[image]

The files do not have sequential filenames like "1.mxd", "2.mxd", etc.  This means the code is going to have to look into the subdirectory, get a filename, pass it to the converter, and go from there.

**Question:**
How do I convert this to an accessible format?

**Thoughts:**
I was thinking about a windows scripting tool like autohotkey or autoit.  Is there a reason those wouldn't work?  It might take a few hours to get it running right, but it isn't going to be taking person weeks of click-click-click.

I like R, MatLab, JMP, and Excel, so anything that speaks an output format that any of those like could work.  R is likely to be the most format agnostic of the bunch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I used "Autohotkey" (aka AHK) and "R".  I could have gone AHK-only, but R just made it faster.  I passed the filename to AHK.  AHK ran mouse and keyboard to operate the MW100 Viewer to open the file, export it, and close it.  This was done for each file needed.

I would open the viewer, maximize it on one monitor, manually open a file in the proper directory so that the local directory was set, then go to R and tell it to read the file names, and feed them one at a time, in 25 second intervals, to the AHK program.

It  ran overnight and I was able to access the CSV data in the morning.

Modified code follows.  Where it says "xx" or "yy" you should put the proper x and y coords for the GUI.

There is no implied anything, this is how I kludged together what I need to in order to do the job.  You can notice the "Escape::", so if you need to kill something just hit the Escape button.

```
;this means when I double-click it reloads, not pops up another instance
#SingleInstance force

; "^j::" means control-j and it starts the script
;^j::
Loop, %0%
{

    ;input parameter is %param%
    myfile := %A_Index%

   ; make "Data Viewer" active
   WinActivate, Data Viewer

   ;click to open a file
    Click, left, xx, yy

   ;wait one second

   ; wait up to 3 seconds for "Data Viewer" to become active
   WinWait, Open, , 3

   ;click area where we type name of file
   click left, 117, 230

   ;send filename
   Send %myfile% {Enter}

   ; wait until "Information" becomes active
   WinWait, Information, , 1

   ;Click "no" on import related files
   click left, xx, yy

   ; it imports, this waits while importing
   Sleep, 2000
   WinActivate, Data Viewer

   ;Click the menu "convert"
   click left, xx, yy

   ;Wait half a second
   Sleep, 500

   ;Click the "to ascii" item
   click left, xx, yy

   ; make "Information" active
   WinWait, ASCII Conversion Details, , 1

   ;click okay
   click left, xx, yy

   ;wait 8 seconds
   Sleep, 14000

   ;click file menu
   click left, xx, yy

   ; wait half a second
   Sleep, 100

   ;select close sub-item
   click left, xx, yy
}

;Return


Escape::
ExitApp
Return
```